# cookies to store in contact form to edit after preview in php

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to get the information submitted by the user to store with a cookie, and redisplay when a user hits 'edit' on the preview page. For example if a user enters "jhon" as name and hits submit, then sees a preview and sees they misspelled their name they can hit edit and all the information they entered is still there, and they only have to fix their name.

Form code:

```
 <!doctype html>
   <?php
   $cookie_name = "first";
  $cookie_value = "$first";
  setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+3600*60*24*7);
  ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Contact Information</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
    <h1>Please Answer the Following Questions</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="form_preview.php">
            <label for="first">First Name: </label>
            <input type="textarea" name="first" />
            <br /><br />
            <label for="last">Last Name: </label>
            <input type="textarea" name="last" />
            <br /><br />
            <label for="first">Email: </label>
            <input type="textarea" name="email" />
            <br /><br />
            <label for="last">Phone Number: </label>
            <input type="textarea" name="phone" />
            <br /><br />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Preview Answers" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Preview code:

```
<!doctype xhtml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Preview</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <?php

$first = $last = $email = $phone = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $first = test_input($_POST["first"]);
  $last = test_input($_POST["last"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
echo "<h1>Personal Information:</h1>";
echo "First Name: ";
echo $first;
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Last Name: ";
echo $last;
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Email: ";
echo $email;
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Phone Number: ";
echo $phone;
echo "<br><br>";

?>

            <form method="post" action="form_entry.php">
                <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
            </form>
            <form method="post" action="form_confirmed.php">
                <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Finish" />
            </form>
      </div>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `cookies` for that? You can easily achieve that using Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: @CWC15 It's part of the criteria for an assignment.